# How to use shell to process json data

Tags: json, shell

How to use shell to process json data?

### Basically, I want it to transform the following:

```
{
  "metric": {
    "hostname": "test-master01",
    "instance": "192.x.x.60",
    "job": "node_exporter"
  },
  "values": [
    [
      1619798400,
      "94.20233550100704"
    ],
    [
      1619971200,
      "94.78123150455177"
    ],
    [
      1620144000,
      "94.78954254601625"
    ]
  ]
}
```

### ... into something like this (Expected output by line)

```
test-master01    192.x.x.60    1620144000    94.78954254601625(max_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

'''
count=$(cat /tmp/pod_cpuperf.json | jq -r '.data.result|length')

```
for ((i=0;i<$count;i++));
do
#   cat /tmp/pod_cpuperf.json | jq -r '.data.result['${i}']' > /tmp/i_cpu_data.json
    cat /tmp/i_cpu_data.json | jq -r '[.metric.hostname,.metric.instance,.metric.job] | @tsv' > /tmp/cpu_line
    cat /tmp/i_cpu_data.json | jq -r '[.values[][1]]|@json' | jq max -r > /tmp/cpu_max
    paste /tmp/cpu_line /tmp/cpu_max >> /tmp/result_cpu_$file.csv
done
```

'''